# Admob in fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, admob

I created an empty project with appcompact and tried to add to it the AdMob block

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.testadmobv.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >
   <LinearLayout    
        android:id="@+id/layout_admob"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {



        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;

             adView = new AdView(getActivity());
             adView.setAdUnitId("MY_AD_UNIT_ID");
             adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
              LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_admob);
            layout.addView(adView);
              AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
              adView.loadAd(adRequest);
            return rootView;

        }
    }
```

In line "adView = new AdView(getActivity());" error "Unreachable code"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
return rootView; // remove this
adView = new AdView(getActivity()); // this is unreachable coz you have return above.
```

The return at the end of `onCreateView` is fine

Comment: Thanks, funny happened, did not see the "return" (

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS THE ANSWER ... you will write root before the findViewById. That's all

```
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) root.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```